# IF THEN in SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a report to return vendor names from journal transactions. Here are the basics of the query below.

I am using data from two views:

- Journal detail view =  `pa_journal_detail`
- Vendor detail view =   `ap_vendor`

Match on Vendor Number:

The vendor number is contained in the following fields:

1. `ap_vendor.a_vendor_number`
2. `pa_journal_detail.jl_ref1` [under certain criteria shown below] ONLY WHEN the journal source code is "API" or "APM"

The source code is stored in the field `pa_journal_detail. jl_source_code`

The vendor name is stored in the field `ap_vendor.a_vendor_name`

This is the query I had started with. It is returning incorrect syntax errors when I attempt to run.

```
SELECT
CASE
          WHEN pa_journal_detail. jl_source_code = ‘API’
               OR pa_journal_detail. jl_source_code = ‘APM’
          THEN(
              SELECT  a_vendor_name
              FROM ap_vendor
              INNER JOIN pa_journal_detail 
              ON pa_journal_detail.jl_ref1 = ap_vendor.a_vendor_number)
          ELSE 0
  END as a_vendor_name, *
  FROM  pa_journal_detail
```

Here is the full query below.  I have also tried it with the "TOP 1" included as well.  I am now getting the error that there is incorrect syntax near the keyword AS.

```
SELECT
   pa_journal_detail.a_project
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_seg2
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_seg3
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_seg4
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_source_code
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_ref1
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_gl_org
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_gl_obj
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_line_num
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_journal_num
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_jnl_year_period
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_journal_number
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_journal_seq
  ,(SELECT(CASE
              WHEN pa_journal_detail. jl_source_code = 'API'
                   OR pa_journal_detail. jl_source_code = 'APM'
              THEN(
                  SELECT TOP 1 a_vendor_name 
                  FROM ap_vendor
                  RIGHT JOIN pa_journal_detail 
                  ON pa_journal_detail.jl_ref1 = ap_vendor.a_vendor_number
                 )
              ELSE 0
      END as 'a_vendor_name', *
      FROM  pa_journal_detail))
FROM pa_journal_detail
```

This is what I ended up with and its working now! Thank you all!

```
SELECT
   pa_journal_detail.a_project
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_seg2
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_seg3
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_seg4
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_source_code
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_ref1
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_gl_org
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_gl_obj
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_line_num
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_journal_num
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_jnl_year_period
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_journal_number
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_journal_seq
  ,iif((pa_journal_detail.jl_source_code = 'API' 
        OR pa_journal_detail.jl_source_code = 'APM')
        ,(SELECT TOP 1 a_vendor_name 
                  FROM ap_vendor
                  RIGHT JOIN pa_journal_detail 
                  ON pa_journal_detail.jl_ref1 = ap_vendor.a_vendor_number)
         ,0) as  'a_vendor_name'
FROM pa_journal_detail
```

Comment: What specific error?  For one thing, that subquery looks like it should be returning more than one row (no correlation between the inside and outside data), which would cause its own problems.  Also, is there some specific reason you didn't use a `LEFT JOIN`?  Generally, using `CASE ... (<subquery>)` should be avoided (although there are specific situations it might help), because in most cases it's going to be obscuring data relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also [iif()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). I use it far more often than I should, I just like have a tiny little if for simple conditional work instead of big ole' Case statement.

```
select iif(1 = 1,'True','False') 
-- any series that results in a boolean
select iif((1 = 1 and 0 = 0) and (5 / 1 = 5 and 5 % 10 = 5),'True','False')
```

for your query

```
SELECT
   pa_journal_detail.a_project
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_seg2
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_seg3
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_seg4
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_source_code
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_ref1
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_gl_org
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_gl_obj
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_line_num
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_journal_num
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_jnl_year_period
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_journal_number
  ,pa_journal_detail.jl_journal_seq
  ,iif(pa_journal_detail.jl_source_code = 'API' OR pa_journal_detail.jl_source_code = 'APM',(SELECT TOP 1 a_vendor_name 
                  FROM ap_vendor
                  RIGHT JOIN pa_journal_detail 
                  ON pa_journal_detail.jl_ref1 = ap_vendor.a_vendor_number)
                 ,0)
              'a_vendor_name', *
      FROM  pa_journal_detail))
FROM pa_journal_detail
```

Answer (score 1):

for string compare you need to use single quote

```
 CASE
              WHEN pa_journal_detail. jl_source_code = 'API'
                   OR pa_journal_detail. jl_source_code = 'APM'
              THEN(
                  SELECT top 1  a_vendor_name -- here you need limit or top 1
                  FROM ap_vendor
                  INNER JOIN pa_journal_detail 
                  ON pa_journal_detail.jl_ref1 = ap_vendor.a_vendor_number
                 )
              ELSE 0
      END as a_vendor_name, *
      FROM  pa_journal_detail
```

Comment: I've tried this way and the example below and am getting this error on both "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Comment: @RebeccaChristian use limit inside subquery btw what is your dbms name

Comment: Its a SQL Server database from my software provider

Comment: @RebeccaChristian then use top 1

Comment: It is better to add 'order by' after top clause

Answer (score 0):

I think a `case` expression may be the wrong tool for the job. If you want to join a table *sometimes*, a `left join` may be easier:

```
SELECT    p.*, a.a_vendor_name
FROM      pa_journal_detail p
LEFT JOIN ap_vendor a ON p.jl_ref1 = a.a_vendor_number AND
          p.jl_source_code IN ('API', 'APM')
```

Comment: When I attempt this way I get the following error:  "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS"

Comment: @RebeccaChristian There is no subquery here. Are you using this snippet as part of some larger query?

Comment: Yes, I was attempting to.

Comment: @RebeccaChristian I may not have been clear enough. This does not replace the `case` expression in the query you shared, but the **entire** query. If this isn't the issue, and you're this query as part of a larger query, please share it, I can't really help without seeing what produced the error.

Comment: I updated the question with the full query. Thanks!

Comment: @RebeccaChristian As I thought, this query can replace the full query that you shared, not just the `case` expression